Matching a polished, lighter and "shinier" font typeface
I want to reproduce the font typeface achieved by this resume (credit: chaitjo).

I could make out the serif font and brick-red color of the links. Out of Cochineal, Linux Libertine, Times and Palatino, Times looked like the closest match. I went with the following options using pdfLaTeX in Overleaf.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% FONTS
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

% COLORS
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=BrickRed
}


I'm not too bothered about the color but the original font has a sharper and lighter feel which I can't replicate using other serif fonts. Any help?

The font looks like Minion Pro (with old style figures active) which is, however not freely available.

If you have a PDF, you can look into the settings where the used fonts are declared, more often than not with their real names.

@JasperHabicht Minion Pro is spot on! Great eye! I do have the PDF file, may I ask which app reveals the used fonts?

@cuffty see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

@cuffty With Acrobat Reader (or Acrobat Pro), you can open the file, go to Menu (or File) > (Document) Properties ...). There, you should find a section with the fonts used in the document.

See this https://bastian.rieck.me/blog/2010/minion/

This short article (identifying a typeface) may be of interest to you. Small items like the differences in the "J"s in "Joshi", or the use of old-style numerals (compare the 5 in "5th July" with the 3 in "3rd September" or the "4"s in "2024") actually have a big impact on the overall appearance of a page/block of text.
As you make those careful comparisons, then you can go to the LaTeX Font Catalogue for available fonts with which to compare each other.

Thank you for the article. Indeed, I was comparing lowercase letter-by-letter but unfortunately LaTeX Font Catalogue does not proprietary fonts like Minion Pro which @Jasper Habicht recognised perfectly.
Looks like we need a better catalogue.

@cuffty Maybe the catalogue needs an update, but note that it does not contain all fonts, but only those which are available as package for (PDF)(La)TeX. To my knowledge, no such package exists for Minion (or a free variant of this font). With XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, you can virtually use every font and therefore these fonts are not included the above linked catalogue and never will be.
